# Load multiple Lucene sharded index onto Solr

Tags: hadoop, solr, lucene

Folks,

I have multiple (count of 100) sharded Lucene indexes (originally generated on Hadoop) and they are of format. The total indexed data is of size 500GB and hence the number of shards.

```
drwxr-x--- 2 index-66
drwxr-x--- 2 index-68
drwxr-x--- 2 index-9
....
....
```

and each index directory is of format

```
$ls index-9
_4.fdt  _4.fdx  _4.fnm  _4_Lucene40_0.frq  _4_Lucene40_0.prx  _4_Lucene40_0.tim  _4_Lucene40_0.tip  _4_nrm.cfe  _4_nrm.cfs  _4.si  segments_1  segments.gen  write.lock
```

Now to load this index, I am currently using Lucene IndexMergeTool to merge all the shards into one giant index. My question is, is there a way to load shared index without merging into one giant index in single collection ?

All the indexes have same schema.

Comment: How do you access the index later on? With Solr or with the Lucene API?

Comment: I will be accessing index via Solr.